# Featured image url

Tags: post-thumbnails, custom-background

I'm trying to create a bootstrap carousel with the featured image as a background in a div. It works for the first post but the second post isn't loading the right background (it loads the one from the first post).

**Code:**

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-header grey-dark">

<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">




<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
    'showposts' => 5,
    'post_type' => array('slider'),
    'orderby' => 1
    ));

// The Loop
if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
    $i = 0;
    while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
        $queryObject->the_post();
        if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>

        <?php global $post; ?>
        <?php
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
        ?>

        <div class="item jumbotron-content active" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $src[0]; ?>');width: 100%;height: 500px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">


            <div class="container">


                  <h2><?php the_title();?><h2>

                  </div>



        </div>


        <?php endif;
        if ( $i != 0 ) : ?>
        <div class="item jumbotron-content" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $src[0]; ?>');width: 100%;height: 500px;display: cover;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">



            <div class="container">

                  <h2><?php the_title();?><h2>

            </div>


        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $i++;
    endwhile;
endif;
  ?>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you getting for the value of `$src[0]` when `$i != 0`?  You know `$i` will either = 0 or not so an `elseif` makes a bit more sense there.

Comment: $i != 0 isn't giving me the featured image URL but does give me the title o the second post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Had to add the same global post after the endif:

```
        <?php endif;
        if ( $i != 0 ) : ?>            

<?php global $post; ?>
        <?php
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
        ?>
```